# DVI monitor not displaying anything

Tags: dvi, cable

I just bought a new graphics card (RX 550), replacing my old Radeon HD 7770 card. I connected the card to my monitor via DVI, the boot screen shows, and then the windows logo, then turns off and says 'no signal'. I connected my other monitor via HDMI and it displays fine... I reinstalled my old Radeon 7770 and reconnected one monitor via DVI and the other via HDMI (dual screen), and both display fine, no problem at all.

Maybe the new card doesn't support the DVI cable I'm using or something?

I also have the newest drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If the DVI cable fits in the RX550 it should work. I had a same issue wiht my RX480. I fixed this by going in to my BIOS settings en play around with the screen input of 'on-board' the switch it to a other option. Try that out.

Answer (score -1):

Is there are a DVI on your Mainboard?
If yes, try to put your Monitor there.

Maybe you have to select a primar screen in your BIOS

Comment: This didn't work